# What is Twig for php template engine?

Tags: php, templates, twig

What is the purpose of using it and what is the basic syntax. I have read the documentation in their site so don't send me the site link as an answer.

Comment: dont use if you are not sure for it..choice is yours.... search for other template engines then..docs are clearly stated ..i wish i could paste the links once more ;)

Answer (score 4):

Twig is a way to make your PHP more object and less messy.

There's a lot of page/web applications that are filled with semi-html-semi-php and that types of PHP page are not very efficient neither maintainable.

By using twig you separate the content from the container. You'll make your code cleaner, easier to maintain and to understand.

Additionally, you can whenever you want change completely the design without affecting the server code in the back.

It's all a question of maintainability and performance and all popular frameworks (Symphony, Code Igniter, etc.) uses these kind of templating tool to make your code cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

Twig (and template engines in general) are a way to streamline display logic using less syntax than normal PHP.  It/they also allow templates to be organized hierarchically, with one inheriting the layout of another.

Template engines mean more overhead in terms of code size and processing, however, as the templates need to be parsed, then executed.